# Getting disconnected from wireless router (Media Link)

Tags: router, wireless-networking

I get disconnected from my wireless router a couple times a day. If I wait 5 or 10 minutes I can get reconnected without restarting the router, then after reconnecting it can take a few minutes until I have internet access.

My previous router I would always stay connected but would sometimes need to restart it in order for the internet to work again (reason for the new router).

Does this sound like an issue with my modem, my router, or my machine? My new router is a media link and is setup with the following settings.

[image]

Comment: Why no aggregation ? What are your clients ?

Comment: I don't know what aggregation is. Clients are PC's, Mac's, iPads, iPhones.